# I am not able to configure Docker VM for Lightbend ConductR. Sandbox init is throwing FileNotFoundError

Tags: docker, sandbox, microservices, lagom

I am trying out Lighbend's ConductR and currently stuck with setting up the sandbox. I followed the instructions given on their [site](https://www.lightbend.com/product/conductr/developer) but I am facing following error at the step "Configure Docker VM" - when I try to do sandbox init:

```
shishir@shishir-VirtualBox:~/Lightbend$ sudo sandbox init
Warning: Docker has an insufficient no. of CPUs 1 - please increase to a minimum of 4 CPUs
Error: Encountered unexpected error.
Error: Reason: FileNotFoundError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker-machine'
Error: Further information of the error can be found in the error log file: /home/shishir/.conductr/errors.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/conductr_cli/main_handler.py", line 8, in run
    result = callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/conductr_cli/sandbox.py", line 6, in main_method
    sandbox_main.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/conductr_cli/sandbox_main.py", line 158, in run
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/conductr_cli/sandbox_init.py", line 32, in init
    if is_docker_machine_installed():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/conductr_cli/sandbox_init.py", line 104, in is_docker_machine_installed
    terminal.docker_machine_help()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/conductr_cli/terminal.py", line 71, in docker_machine_help
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True).strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 693, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'docker-machine'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sandbox", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('conductr-cli==0.39', 'console_scripts', 'sandbox')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/conductr_cli/sandbox.py", line 10, in run
    main_handler.run(main_method)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/conductr_cli/main_handler.py", line 31, in run
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(DEFAULT_ERROR_LOG_FILE, maxBytes=3000000, backupCount=1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/handlers.py", line 150, in __init__
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/handlers.py", line 57, in __init__
    logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1008, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1037, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/shishir/.conductr/errors.log'
```

I am trying to run it on Ubuntu Virtual Box. Here is the uname output:

```
shishir@shishir-VirtualBox:~$ uname -a
Linux shishir-VirtualBox 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have installed Docker and Python3 as per the instructions.

I am not sure whats causing the issue but seems like there is something missing in the guide. Any help in solving this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sandbox init` command currently expects that `docker-machine` is installed. On Linux, this is not the case. Instead, native `docker-engine` is used. So this is a bug and as a result, the `sandbox init` command is currently not supported on Linux. The PR https://github.com/typesafehub/conductr-cli/pull/139 is addressing this. Once the PR is merged the `sandbox init` command will be supported on all operation systems.

Nevertheless, you don't need to wait until this issue has been fixed. The `sandbox init` command only checks that the VM you want to run ConductR on, in your case Ubuntu Virtual Box, has sufficient resources to start ConductR. All other commands are working on Linux. I would advise using a VM with at least 4 CPUs and 4 GiB of memory. ConductR alone does not need so many resources so it highly depends on what you want to run on ConductR and how many ConductR instances you want to run in your VM. The max heap of a ConductR core node itself is set to 256 MB of memory, the max heap for a ConductR agent node is set to 128 MB of memory.

**Resource Example**

- 3 ConductR core nodes:  768  MB
- 3 Conductr agent nodes: 384  MB
- ConductR total:         1152 MB

So in the case of a VM with 4 GiB you almost have 3 GiB available for the services you want to run on ConductR, e.g. Lagom, Cassandra, Akka, other Docker images.

Comment: Thanks for information Markus. I will keep an eye on the pull request. The Lightbend team suggested that I can directly do a "sandbox run" but that command says throws an error: "The docker service has not been started" - although it is running. Not sure what the problem is.